# I can't turn Ubuntu on

Tags: boot, system, fsck

When I turn my Dell Precision 3500 laptop on and try to get into Ubuntu, I can't do so. I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and Microsoft Windows 10 on laptop. Many words appear on screen when I try booting to Ubuntu. Among what appear to be the most diagnostic are these: "The root file system on /dev/nvme0n1p6 requests a manual fsck" and "Busybox v1.30.1 (ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4 ubuntu 6.2) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands." I have no idea what a "manual fsck" is. I enter "help" and get a paragraph of what appears to be mainly nonsense.

Can someone help me figure out what to do to get Ubuntu back up and running?

Thanks.

P.S. I tried following the instructions I was given in the response below, without success. I guess I don't know what some of the terms mean. What does it mean to "boot off a Unbuntu installer drive?" is that a different drive than the one that I'm having trouble with? Also, what does "use fsck (see man fsck)" mean, and how do I do it. Lastly, I did go into Windows and search for "Fast Boot" in settings so I could disable it, but I couldn't find it there. What should I do?

Thanks.

"fsck is a command-line tool for find errors in, and repairing, damaged disks. You should boot of a Ubuntu installer drive, and use fsck (see man fsck) to repair your disk, and post your results. Also make sure you have disabled Windows Fast Boot in Windows settings."

Comment: `fsck` is a command-line tool for find errors in, and repairing, damaged disks. You should boot of a Ubuntu installer drive, and use `fsck` (see `man fsck`) to repair your disk, and post your results. Also make sure you have disabled Windows Fast Boot in Windows settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely do to your disk being corrupted or damaged. "`fsck` is a command line tool" means that it is a program that does not have a GUI, or graphical user interface, thus it must be run from a terminal. `man` is a command used to read the manual for a specified command, in this case, `fsck`. Booting off a Live CD is just like you did to install ubuntu, except chose "Try Ubuntu" instead of install. You can then open `terminal` from the applications menu in the upper left and use it to run the previously mentioned commands. You can see more details on using `fsck` [here](https://net2.com/using-fsck-to-check-or-repair-the-file-system-in-ubuntu/).
Additioanlly, I apologize for the late response; I forgot to hit the "follow" button. In future, you may want to comment and tag users with `@username` after responding to them with an edit so that they are notified. Please comment on this post if you have any other questions.